# How to see which plugins are making Vim slow?

Tags: debugging, optimization, vim, macvim

Is there a way to profile Vim plugins?

My MacVim becomes slower and slower when I open a large `.py`. I know I could deselect all plugins and reselect one by one to check which plugin is the culprit, but is there a faster way?

My dotvim is here: https://github.com/charlax/dotvim

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687799/profiling-vim-startup-time

Comment: Actually, startup is fine. Vim becomes slow after a few minutes of use. It especially concerns `.py` files.

Comment: Binary search *is* the way to go. You have asked your question 2 hours ago, the cause of your problem would have been found in that time. Ingo Karkat's `autocmd` hunch sounds the mst plausible to me.

Comment: That's true - but don't you think that if there's a way to get the same result in even one hour, that's better? What's more, startup is fine, it's after a few minutes of use, so it would have taken a very long time. `autocmd` looks cool. Just tried it but Vim is not slow right now.

Comment: Just faced same issue, but on big ruby files. Found that `folding=syntax` can slow down. Tried with `folding=manual` and now everything works fine

Answer (score 590, accepted):

You can use built-in profiling support: after launching vim do

```
:profile start profile.log
:profile func *
:profile file *
" At this point do slow actions
:profile pause
:noautocmd qall!
```

(unlike quitting `noautocmd` is not really required, it just makes vim quit faster).

Note: you won’t get information about functions there were deleted before vim quit.

Comment: This is amazing. I was able to see that EasyTags is the culprit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This really helped me. I found that vim-signify and tagbar were slowing down vim a LOT. Not worth it!

Comment: this helped me to detect "vim-gitgutter" as the clog.

Comment: Found the slowness is due to syntax file is sourced multiple times. Have specified filetype in vim modeline & also assigning the filetype in .vimrc based on file extension. So, syntax file is sourced 2 times.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I also found out tagbar was causing the problem. Finally usable again :)

Comment: @blushrt I do not remember any patch altering `:profile` support in 7.4.\* series. This is also useless to complain without giving details.

Comment: @ZyX E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version. More useful now ?

Comment: @blushrt You have Vim without profiling support compiled in. You need to get Vim with it.

Comment: How can you identify a specific plugin as being the primary cause of poor performance? I can get information such as below, but am still unclear about what is responsible for calling this and what should be done about it.

    `FUNCTION  <SNR>51_Highlight_Matching_Pair()`
    `Called 1 time`
    `Total time:   0.669410`
     `Self time:   0.669410`

Comment: @subjectego `:set more | verbose function {function_name}` will show you function contents and where it is located.

Comment: Very cool but nothing I found nothing super obvious in terms of time or number of calls, but powerline was overrepresented which lead me to installing lightline instead, so overall learned two new things, thanks!

Comment: If it's not clear, the resulting `profile.log` is a file in your Vim session's current directory.

Comment: Just for reference: it seems that https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine was the culprit for me

Comment: Jump to the end of `profile.log` to see the list of functions sorted by total time (`profile.log` seemed useless to me before I found it there is a sorted list at the end).

Comment: Another FYI - Airline was culprit for me.

Comment: Is it possible to create the log without quitting vim?

Comment: Found the culprit to be vim-devicons

Comment: My `profile.log` has lines like this: `6   5.828956   3.819220  <SNR>98_cache()`. How can I find where the function `<SNR>98_cache()` lives?

Comment: Thank you Jesus. vim-airline-clock was fetching the new time every -1 seconds whatever that means, besides a billion times per second. I was able to fix it and got my esc key back.

Comment: For future reference, `vim-syntastic` was the culprit for files with 10K+ lines. Took ~2s for single cursor movement

Comment: Does anyone made already a key bidding with function that will call these commands? That will make debug easier.

Comment: @milushov Not a great case for key-binding, IMO. You could put the lines in a file and do `:so filename` on those occasions when you need it. If you really use it a lot then `:nnoremap XXX :so filename` (with XXX whatever you want). ;)

Comment: Here's a oneliner for the first three lines: `:profile start profile.log | profile func * | profile file *`

Answer (score 94):

I found another very helpful vim buildin method to show the exactly timing messages while loading your .vimrc.

```
vim --startuptime timeCost.txt timeCost.txt
```

Please run:

```
:help --startuptime
```

in VIM to get more information.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is wondering, this doesn't exist in all vim/gvim distros. Doesn't in a stock Win Gvim 7.4 over here (though it is documented in viminfo)

Comment: @thynctank I tried on my gvim 7.4 and it worked. Here is my version `IM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 10 2013 14:33:40)`

Comment: Best answer! Helped me to identify the slowest plugin that made me angry at every vim start. Thanx :)

Comment: This and basic `-V` showed it was a non-local `$HOME` causing the issue

Comment: You need to execute `:e` to refresh the file. Sort the file in place according to the total time taken for each op like so `:%! sort -k2 -nr`

Comment: This helped me to find out X11 forwarding the culprit for slow start up. After disabling in my terminal, it just worked fine.

Answer (score 31):

It could be a plugin or the syntax highlighting; try a `:syntax off` when this happens and see whether Vim instantly gets faster.

With plugins, a "general slowness" usually comes from autocommands; a `:autocmd` lists them all. Investigate by killing some of them via `:autocmd! [group] {event}`. Proceed from more frequent events (i.e. `CursorMoved[I]`) to less frequent ones (e.g. `BufWinEnter`).

If you can somewhat reliably reproduce the slowness, a binary search might help: Move away half of the files in `~/.vim/plugin/`, then the other, repeat in the set that was slow.

If you really need to look under the hood, get a Vim version that has the `:profile` command enabled. (Not the vanilla BIG Windows version, but the one that ships with Cygwin has it; also, self-compiling is quite easy under most distros.)

Answer (score 18):

I have found it helpful to print all Vim activity to a file by starting Vim with the `-V` option:

```
vim -V12log
```

This provides the maximum verbosity (level 12) and outputs it to the file `log`. You can then perform some Vim actions which you know to be slow, and then see which functions/mappings are being called internally.

Comment: but there are no timing on the log

Answer (score 14):

If you're having problems with screen update operations (`^L`, scrolling, etc) being slow, your problem may be an inefficient syntax highlighting file. You can test this by temporarily disabling syntax highlighting (`:syn off`) and seeing if the problem goes away; if you want to dig into the details, you can profile the current syntax file using `:syntime`:

1. Open a file that causes syntax highlighting performance issues.
2. Run `:syntime on` to start profiling.
3. Scroll through the file a bit.
4. Run `:syntime report` to generate a report. The patterns listed first in the report are the ones which took the most time to process.

Comment: If it does seem like the syntax highlight file is the culprit, what's the next course of action?

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution: Find one slow command. Move one plugin to `/tmp/`. Try the command again. If it's still slow, move another plugin to `/tmp/`. Repeat, until you find the plugin that makes the command slow.

Comment: If you're using lazy.nvim (https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim), you can easily disable plugins by setting `enabled = false`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using lazy.nvim (github.com/folke/lazy.nvim), you can do something like this:

```lua
disabled_plugins = { }

-- If there are plugins here, they will be the only enabled ones.
enable_just_these_plugins = { }

plugins = {}

-- This allows us to modify all the plugins before we load them.
local function add(plugin)
  if type(plugin) == "string" then
    plugin = { plugin }
  end
  if vim.tbl_contains(disabled_plugins, plugin[1]) then
    print('disabling plugin: ' .. plugin[1])
    plugin.enabled = false
    return
  end
  if #enable_just_these_plugins == 0 or vim.tbl_contains(enable_just_these_plugins, plugin[1]) then
    table.insert(plugins, plugin)
  end
end
```

Then you can do:

```lua
add "abeldekat/lazyflex.nvim"
add "SmiteshP/nvim-gps"
-- and so on, and finally:
require("lazy").setup(plugins, lazy_options)
```

Add the names of plugins to `disabled_plugins` or `enable_just_these_plugins` to temporarily switch them off.