# How to profile the startup time of Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Launching my powershell takes about 3 sec, so I want to reduce it.
How do I know which process harms the startup performance of powershell?
I want to use a tool like [vim profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216578/10051099).

Comment: It is probably your profile. try running a `Measure-Command` on your entire profile.

Comment: @Drew thanks! I wrote `$profile.psobject.properties | where { $_ -is [psnoteproperty] } | foreach { echo $_.value; Measure-Command { . $_
.value }}`

Comment: @Yohei there is a useless space in your script. Maybe `$_  .value` should be `$_.value`?

Answer (score 1):

**Set-PSDebug approach:** To quickly see if your profile is slow, you can add

```
Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
```

to the top of your profile. You'll then be able to watch the individual lines being executed in real-time. Add `Set-PSDebug -Trace 0` to the bottom of your profile to turn it off.

**Measuring your multiple $PROFILE files:** To measure the different profile files automatically contained in your current $PROFILE:

```
$PROFILE | gm -Type NoteProperty | % {($path=$PROFILE.($_.Name)); Measure-Command{&{. $path}}}
```

**Measure-Command within your profile:** You can also wrap individual commands or your entire profile in `Measure-Command` by editing your profile file. For example, to report your profile's execution time:

```
$executionTime = Measure-Command `
{
    # Your profile commands here
}

# $PSCommandPath is an automatic variable containing the path and file name of
# the script being run.
Write-Host "$PSCommandPath execution time: $executionTime"
```