# Vim - Inserting Newlines in Python is Extremely Slow

Tags: vim, neovim

For some reason, when I insert a newline in vim (either with the o key, or an enter), it takes quite a bit of time for vim to actually insert the new line.
This problem is exacerbated when I press and hold the enter key - in this case, vim totally freezes, and takes about 3-4 seconds to render all of the new lines.
This problem seems to be specific to Python files, as I have tested this behavior with other large non-python files, and do not see this problem.

Some of the slowdown is caused by the vim-polyglot language pack, but disabling that plugin only helped the slowdown a little bit, not eliminate it completely.
Opening a file with `vim -u NORC` also didn't help much at all, and the only way I was able to finally get smooth inserting of newlines is with `vim -u NONE` or `syntax off`, leading me to believe that this is a syntax highlighting problem.

Here's the syntime report for just holding down the enter key for a couple of seconds (with `-u NORC`:

```
  TOTAL      COUNT  MATCH   SLOWEST     AVERAGE   NAME               PATTERN
  0.467286   11548  0       0.000109    0.000040  pythonMatrixMultiply ^\s*\%(\%(>>>\|\.\.\.\)\s\+\)\=\zs\%(\h\|\%(\h\|[[(]\).\{-}\%(\w\|[])]\)\)\s*\n\%(\s*\.\.\.\s\)\=\s\+@\%(.\{-}\n\%(\s*\.\.\.\s\)\=\s\+@\)*
  0.404281   12396  968     0.000109    0.000033  pythonNumber       \%(^\|\W\)\zs\d*\.\d\+\%([eE][+-]\=\d\+\)\=[jJ]\=\>
  0.376318   11548  0       0.000085    0.000033  pythonString       [uU]\=\z('''\|"""\)
  0.340580   11548  0       0.000222    0.000029  pythonMatrixMultiply \%(\w\|[])]\)\s*@
  0.263625   14333  5095    0.000063    0.000018  pythonString       [uU]\=\z(['"]\)
  0.250727   11548  0       0.000058    0.000022  pythonRawString    [uU]\=[rR]\z('''\|"""\)
  0.241550   11548  0       0.000061    0.000021  pythonRawString    [uU]\=[rR]\z(['"]\)
  0.229741   21954  13645   0.000047    0.000010  pythonNumber       \<\%([1-9]\d*\|0\)[Ll]\=\>
  0.228875   11548  0       0.000392    0.000020  pythonNumber       \<\d\+\.\%([eE][+-]\=\d\+\)\=[jJ]\=\%(\W\|$\)\@=
  0.202706   11548  0       0.000050    0.000018  pythonMatrixMultiply [^\\]\\\s*\n\%(\s*\.\.\.\s\)\=\s\+@
  0.175705   11548  0       0.000040    0.000015  pythonNumber       \<\d\+[eE][+-]\=\d\+[jJ]\=\>
  0.171692   11548  0       0.000047    0.000015  pythonNumber       \<\d\+[jJ]\>
  0.059275   24104  16355   0.000032    0.000002  pythonAttribute    \.\h\w*
  0.047092   11660  2977    0.000035    0.000004  pythonComment      #.*$
  0.021249   4826   4826    0.000020    0.000004  pythonString       \z1
  0.008962   11548  0       0.000015    0.000001  pythonNumber       \<0[xX]\x\+[Ll]\=\>
  0.008958   11548  0       0.000015    0.000001  pythonNumber       \<0[oO]\=\o\+[Ll]\=\>
  0.008755   11548  0       0.000004    0.000001  pythonNumber       \<0[bB][01]\+[Ll]\=\>
  0.004358   11548  952     0.000016    0.000000  pythonEscape       \\$
  0.003670   11484  0       0.000017    0.000000  pythonDecoratorName @\s*\h\%(\w\|\.\)*
  0.001265   4760   0       0.000001    0.000000  pythonEscape       \\N{\a\+\%(\s\a\+\)*}
  0.001153   4826   0       0.000001    0.000000  pythonString       \\\\\|\\\z1
  0.001129   4760   0       0.000001    0.000000  pythonEscape       \%(\\u\x\{4}\|\\U\x\{8}\)
  0.001116   4760   0       0.000001    0.000000  pythonEscape       \\[abfnrtv'"\\]
  0.001098   4760   0       0.000001    0.000000  pythonEscape       \\\o\{1,3}
  0.001072   4760   0       0.000001    0.000000  pythonEscape       \\x\x\{2}
  0.000749   3104   0       0.000001    0.000000  pythonDecorator    @
  0.000700   3119   0       0.000001    0.000000  pythonDoctestValue ^\s*\%(>>>\s\|\.\.\.\s\|"""\|'''\)\@!\S\+
  0.000601   3119   0       0.000010    0.000000  pythonDoctest      ^\s*>>>\s
  0.000068   62     0       0.000007    0.000001  pythonSync         ^\%(def\|class\)\s\+\h\w*\s*[(:]

  3.524359   288911
```

I'm not entirely sure why there is so many regexes being matched, as the only thing I'm doing is inserting new lines.  Furthermore, most of these regexes, such as pythonMatrixMultiply, aren't even matching anything.
Any help would be appreciated.
For reference, here is my vim and neovim versions (I mostly use neovim, but this problem happens in vim as well).

```
NVIM v0.3.1
```

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 07 2019 11:40:34)
```

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003

Answer (score 1):

Since `-u NORC` keeps the plugins available, whereas `-u NONE` turns everything off, it seems likely that a plugin is causing your issue. Further detective work would involve gradually adding back plugins until you discover the culprit.

In the context of Neovim, you could also run `:checkhealth` which can sometimes show up issues with the Python2 and Python3 providers.

Finally, you may also find [this answer about Vim profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216578/122643) helpful.