# Vim Editor .vimrc error during customizaiton

Tags: vim, vi

I has suffered while customizing my vim editor.

Specifically, I add function which store cursor location.

Below is my .vimrc file.

```
au BufReadPost *
\ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
\ exe "norm g`\"" |
\ endif
```

And Error content is below :

```
au: command not found
-bash: /home/ubuntu/.vimrc: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /home/ubuntu/.vimrc: line 24: `\ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |'
```

Could you give me the solution ?
Take care of your health during COVID-19.
Thanks !

---

I found solution that change file authority.

```
chmod +777 ~/.viminfo
```

.vimsrc file compiled still suffering error.

But function that restore cursor position is working.

Reference : https://askubuntu.com/questions/202075/how-do-i-get-vim-to-remember-the-line-i-was-on-when-i-reopen-a-file

Comment: Those are not vim errors, those are bash errors.  Did you source your .vimrc in vim or in bash?

Comment: @RandyMorris Thank you for comment. I edit my .vimrc and run the command like this source ~/.vimrc. And then i met this error.

Comment: Where do you input `source ~/.vimrc`? This must be at the command line within vim. Enter `vim`, then type `:`.

Comment: @evnu Thank tou for comment. But i cannot understand. You means that 1. vi ~/.vimrc 2. Edit Content 3. :source ~/.vimrc. Is it right ? But it isn't changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+bash+syntax+error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to source .vimrc from the command line, this will be done automatically by vim. Just make sure it's in the right place ($HOME/.vimrc)

Then when you open vim, it will source automatically.

You can view how to debug, where you will see if your file has been sourced in this answer [How to see which plugins are making Vim slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213597/how-to-see-which-plugins-are-making-vim-slow)

Comment: Thank you for comment. I located .vimrc file in $Home(/home/ubuntu). But still suffer same problem :(