# How do you capture vim debugger output to a file or register?

Tags: vim

I'm debugging a vim script:

```
:breakadd here
:redir >somefile.txt
:so %
```

Expected Output:

```
   Entering Debug mode.  Type "cont" to continue.
    /some/path/somescript.vim
    line 327: execute 'echom ' .  "'done'"
    >step
    /some/path/somescript.vim
    line 327: echom 'done'
    >step
    done
    /some/path/somescript.vim
    line 335: End of sourced file
    >finish
:redir END
:e somefile.txt
```

Instead I get:

```
 -- INSERT --

    1 line less; before #1  1 second ago
    1 line less; before #1  1 second ago
    Already at oldest change

    Breakpoint in "/some/path/somescript.vim" line 327
    done
```

Workaround - For now just copy and paste the output with my mouse or scriptease.

```
:Verbose messages
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213597/how-to-see-which-plugins-are-making-vim-slow) answer will help

Comment: Vim profile ? I'm not wanting to see what scripts are slowing down my vim. I'm wanting to output the debug messages from ```:debug``` ```breakadd here``` into a file. The work around is to just do Verbose messages and ```:v\line\d``` delete all the lines I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around is to use `:Verbose messages`